# My tensorboard events appear many charts I did not summary

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I only summary my loss as 'xentropy_mean' in training() ,but in tensorboard ,I had not find the 'xentropy_mean' chart but many other charts I did not defined. I don't know where I wrote wrong, and what's the matter indeed. Is it because I use thread in my code? If I don't use thread, how should I wrote it?

[The tensorboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELM2s.png) 
There are 6 charts under the queue,I don't know what are the meanings either

I create the model in the file below

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import math

import tensorflow.python.platform
import tensorflow as tf

# The MNIST dataset has 10 classes, representing the digits 0 through 9.
NUM_CLASSES = 16

# The MNIST images are always 28x28 pixels.
IMAGE_SIZE = 28
IMAGE_PIXELS = 784


def inference(images, hidden1_units, hidden2_units):
  """Build the MNIST model up to where it may be used for inference.

  Args:
    images: Images placeholder, from inputs().
    hidden1_units: Size of the first hidden layer.
    hidden2_units: Size of the second hidden layer.

  Returns:
    softmax_linear: Output tensor with the computed logits.
  """
  # Hidden 1
  with tf.name_scope('hidden1'):
    weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([IMAGE_PIXELS, hidden1_units],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(IMAGE_PIXELS))),
        name='weights')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_units]),
                         name='biases')
    hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(images, weights) + biases)
  # Hidden 2
  with tf.name_scope('hidden2'):
    weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([hidden1_units, hidden2_units],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden1_units))),
        name='weights')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden2_units]),
                         name='biases')
    hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1, weights) + biases)
  # Linear
  with tf.name_scope('softmax_linear'):
    weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([hidden2_units, NUM_CLASSES],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden2_units))),
        name='weights')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_CLASSES]),
                         name='biases')
    logits = tf.matmul(hidden2, weights) + biases
  return logits


def loss(logits, labels):

  batch_size = tf.size(labels)
  #print('batch size %d' %(batch_size))
  labels = tf.expand_dims(labels, 1)
  indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, batch_size), 1)
  concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, labels])
  #print('Done2')
  onehot_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(
      concated, tf.pack([batch_size, 16]), 1.0, 0.0)
  #print('Done1')
  cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,
                                                          onehot_labels,
                                                          name='xentropy')
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
  tf.summary.scalar(loss.op.name, loss)

  return loss


def training(loss, learning_rate):
  optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
  global_step=tf.Variable(0,name='global_step',trainable=False)
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

  return train_op


def evaluation(logits, labels):


  correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)
  # Return the number of true entries.
  return tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct, tf.int32))
```

and train the model in this file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import os.path
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

import mnist


# Basic model parameters as external flags.
#FLAGS = None

# Constants used for dealing with the files, matches convert_to_records.
TRAIN_FILE = 'train.tfrecords'
VALIDATION_FILE = 'validation.tfrecords'
TEST_FILE='test.tfrecords'


flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
#FLAGS = None
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', '/home/queenie/image2tfrecord/tfrecords-28-gray/', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_string('filename', 'train.tfrecords', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 100, 'Batch size.  '
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_epochs', None, 'Batch size.  '
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden1', 128,'balabala')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden2', 32,'balabala')
flags.DEFINE_integer('learning_rate', 0.01,'balabala')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 50000,'balabala')


def placeholder_inputs(batch_size):
  images_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(batch_size,mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS))
  labels_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=(batch_size))
  return images_placeholder,labels_placeholder

def fill_feed_dict(images_feed,labels_feed,images_pl,labels_pl):

  feed_dict={
  images_pl:images_feed,
  labels_pl:labels_feed,
  }
  return feed_dict

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
      features={
          'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      })

  # Convert from a scalar string tensor (whose single string has
  # length mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS) to a uint8 tensor with shape
  # [mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS].
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image.set_shape([mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS])

  # OPTIONAL: Could reshape into a 28x28 image and apply distortions
  # here.  Since we are not applying any distortions in this
  # example, and the next step expects the image to be flattened
  # into a vector, we don't bother.

  # Convert from [0, 255] -> [-0.5, 0.5] floats.
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5

  # Convert label from a scalar uint8 tensor to an int32 scalar.
  label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)

  return image, label


def do_eval(sess,eval_correct):
    true_count=0
    for step in xrange(FLAGS.batch_size):
        #print(sess.run(eval_correct))
        true_count+=sess.run(eval_correct)

    precision=float(true_count)/FLAGS.batch_size/FLAGS.batch_size
    print('  Num examples: %d  Num correct: %d  Precision @ 1: %0.04f' %
(FLAGS.batch_size, true_count, precision))
    return precision


def inputs(train, batch_size, num_epochs):

  if not num_epochs: num_epochs = None
  if train=='train':
    filename=os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir,TRAIN_FILE)
  elif train=='validation':
    filename=os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir,VALIDATION_FILE)
  else:
    filename=os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir,TEST_FILE)


  # filename = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir,
  #                         TRAIN_FILE if train else VALIDATION_FILE)

  with tf.name_scope('input'):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        [filename], num_epochs=None)

    # Even when reading in multiple threads, share the filename
    # queue.
    image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

    # Shuffle the examples and collect them into batch_size batches.
    # (Internally uses a RandomShuffleQueue.)
    # We run this in two threads to avoid being a bottleneck.
    images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
        capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
        # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
        min_after_dequeue=1000)

    return images, sparse_labels


def run_training():



  with tf.Graph().as_default():



    # Build a Graph that computes predictions from the inference model.
    images, labels = inputs(train='train', batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                            num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)

    images_valid,labels_valid=inputs(train='validation', batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                             num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)

    images_test,labels_test=inputs(train='test', batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                             num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)

    logits = mnist.inference(images,
                             FLAGS.hidden1,
                             FLAGS.hidden2)
    # Add to the Graph the loss calculation.

    valid_prediction=mnist.inference(images_valid,FLAGS.hidden1,FLAGS.hidden2)

    test_prediction=mnist.inference(images_test,FLAGS.hidden1,FLAGS.hidden2)



    loss = mnist.loss(logits, labels)

    # Add to the Graph operations that train the model.
    train_op = mnist.training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

    eval_correct=mnist.evaluation(logits,labels)

    eval_correct_valid=mnist.evaluation(valid_prediction,labels_valid)

    eval_correct_test=mnist.evaluation(test_prediction,labels_test)

    summary_op=tf.merge_all_summaries()
    # The op for initializing the variables.
    init_op = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(),
                       tf.initialize_local_variables())

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # Create a session for running operations in the Graph.
    sess = tf.Session()


    # Initialize the variables (the trained variables and the
    # epoch counter).
    sess.run(init_op)

    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)

    # Start input enqueue threads.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    try:
      step = 0
      train_precision=0
      validation_precision=0
      test_precision=0
      #while not coord.should_stop():
      while not coord.should_stop():
        start_time = time.time()


        _, loss_value,images_see,labels_see = sess.run([train_op, loss,images,labels])
        #print('run done')

        duration = time.time() - start_time


        # Print an overview fairly often.
        if step % 100 == 0:
          print('Step %d: loss = %.2f (%.3f sec)' % (step, loss_value,
                                                     duration))
          precision_tr=do_eval(sess,eval_correct)
          summary_str=sess.run(summary_op)
          summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str,step)


        if (step + 1) % 1000 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps:
          checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, 'model.ckpt')
          saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file, global_step=step)
          print('Train:')
          do_eval(sess,eval_correct)
          print('Validation:')
          do_eval(sess,eval_correct_valid)
          print('Test:')
          do_eval(sess,eval_correct_test)

        step += 1

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      print('Done training for %d epochs, %d steps.' % (FLAGS.num_epochs, step))
    finally:
      # When done, ask the threads to stop.
      coord.request_stop()

    # Wait for threads to finish.
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()


run_training()
```

then I get the tensorboard like these,6 charts about queue.
[The tensorboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asWIH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue charts you are seeing are created by default from shuffle_batch and friends, and can be used to monitor the performance of your input pipeline (you'll ideally want all the queues to stay at capacity, as that means your GPU isn't blocking on input reading).

I don't understand why your summary isn't showing in tensorboard. Can I get more information?

Comment: Thank you soooo much, I have gave up for solving it for 3 days. After seeing your answer, I examined it and looked the examples in tensorflow again, I found I wrote "tf.summary.scalar(loss.op.name, loss)" in wrong place. I replace it from the function loss() to the function training(), the problem was solved. 
Maybe it seems to be a little stupid, but I am so  happy I fixed it.
Thank you so much:-)